# How to pass a value from WinForm (C#) to an altogether separate Javascript client chat application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, winforms, xmpp

I have a chat application in which I have a client side(javascript) and server-side which is WinForms. I want to pass a value from my FrmConsole.cs file to my converse.js file. Is there any way I can achieve this? I am using XMPP protocol for connecting the client and operator console and I have my own ejabberd server running for the same. 
For Example I want to pass this string from my C# code to my Javascript file:

```cs
private string GetStringValue()
{
  return "A string value";
}
```

And this would be my javascript side code:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var stringValue = '<%=GetStringValue();%>';

  alert(stringValue);
</script>
```

I tried this but its not throwing the expected alert. In the alert it shows

```html
<%=GetStringValue();%>
```

Comment: Is that Javascript part of an ASPX page?

Comment: No its a completely separate javascript library working independently as a client

Comment: That'll be your problem then, as you're trying to embed ASPX markup in a file that isn't an ASPX file

Comment: Isnt there any solution or any way around it?

Comment: asp.net is not `winform` , it is `webform`.

Comment: Sorry,my bad i had got them confused up hence have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showstring(){
         var stringValue = '<%=GetStringValue();%>';
         alert(stringValue);
 </script>
```

main body:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:showstring();", true);
```

Comment: Sorry this answer does not apply as i have realised it is not an ASP.NET application but a WinForm and have hence edited the question.My Apologies